# Skillet Cooked Shrimp Texture

Tags: cooking-time, shrimp

I was wondering exactly what a perfectly cooked shrimp's texture should be.  I know the "rubbery" texture means over cooked and that if it's clear in the middle it's undercooked.  But in terms of mouth feel and texture what should I expect? There is a "crunch" to each bite, almost like I'm breaking through some sort of layer.  I just don't know if this is normal or not.  I cooked the shrimp in a non-stick skillet on medium heat for about 5-6 minutes total and flipped the shrimp every 30-45 seconds.

Comment: That sounds about right to me. I tend to think of the texture as a "pop" that indicates plenty of internal juices. There might be more of a culinary term for that which I don't know, so I'll leave that to others and post this as an answer later if there aren't better submissions.

Comment: Yeah that sounds right to me. My opinion is however that a little overlooked is better than a little undercooked. I can't stand undercooked shrimp.

Answer (score 1):

The doneness of something is obviously a matter of a opinion, but based on the comments I received the "crunch" in each bite is normal. It is overcooked if it is tough and rubbery and it is undercooked if you cut it open and you see white on the outside but a clear-ish color towards the middle.